# $f(x)\in O(\frac{1}{x})$ implies $\log(f(x))\in O(\frac{1}{x^2})$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Consider a function $f(x):(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $f(x)\in O(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ where Big O notation is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Is it true that

$$
\log(f(x))\in O(\frac{1}{x^2})
$$

as $x \rightarrow 0$

If Yes, could you help me to show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. For example, consider

$$
f(x) = \exp(-1/x^4).
$$

Then $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, so certainly $f(x) \in O(1/x)$ as $x \to 0$. But definitely

$$
\log f(x) \notin O(1/x^2)
$$

as $x \to 0$.